# Using cleaned_data.get("field") results in AttributError when form is not printed

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Good day SO!

I have an odd situation which I don't understand. I have a FormView in which an user can fill in an username or e-mail to recover an account's password. In the view FormView I got the following situation:

```
class RecoverPassword(FormView):
    """ Request password recovery by username or email address """

    template_name = "users/recover.html"
    form_class = RecoverPasswordForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print(form) # <<<--- Removing this results in an error
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")

        if username:
            print(username)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

This works, and the filled username is shown in the Terminal.
However, if I remove the following line:

```
print(form)
```

and fill in the form with an username and hit submit, I get the following
error:

> Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value: 'RecoverPasswordForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

I just can't figure out why this is happening. Does somebody know what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do this in `post`? Use `form_valid` method instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")

    if username:
        print(username)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```